# Snowflake truncate gets rolledback

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using python to truncate a table in snowflake

```
    truncate_table_query = f'truncate table {database}.{schema}.{table_name};'
    with engine.connect() as con:
        con.execute(truncate_table_query)
```

The problem I am facing is that the statements executes but the tables are not truncating.  According to the log I think the statement is automatically rolled back.

```
INFO:snowflake.connector.cursor:query: [truncate table db.schema.table;]
INFO:snowflake.connector.cursor:query execution done
INFO:snowflake.connector.json_result:fetching data done
INFO:snowflake.connector.cursor:query: [ROLLBACK]
INFO:snowflake.connector.cursor:query execution done
INFO:snowflake.connector.connection:closed
```

What am I missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to enable auto-commit auto commit while creating the connection engine.

```
engine = create_engine(URL(...)).execution_options(autocommit=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, autocommit is turned on, but you are not closing the connection, so it is rolling back the changes.  Try adding this after your execute:

```
with engine.connect() as con:
try:
     con.execute(truncate_table_query)
     commit()
finally:
     con.close()
```

Comment: Connection doesn't have the commit method.

Comment: I solve this by enabling auto commit and closing the connection. Your suggestion helped. Thanks.